# How to cancel a PHP process, when ajax call is cancelled?

Tags: php, ajax, search, request

i am currently working on a CRM system with a huge database.
If the user wants to search a customer, he can use the ajax search. Everytime he changes something in the search field, while a call is pending, the old call is cancelled and a new one will be send to the server.
My problem is, that the php processes on server side continue running. So if the user starts typing in an address, several requests are started and cancelled and the server needs more and more time to answer.

Is is possible to cancel the running php process, when the ajax call is cancelled? 
Or is there a possible solution on server side, to detect if a search request from the same user is running and cancel it before starting the new one?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: you can limit a number character need to full in search box or when comes on search box and types you search it there with jQuery ajax.

Comment: You should start search if only user hits "Search" button or hits enter key.

Comment: If it is taking so long to do your search lookup that the process lags the server down when its running multiple times, you need to optimise your search routines, rather than trying to kill already running processes. Put a key on the search column and it should take fractions of a second to fetch the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for ignore_user_abort()  ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: read the note: PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. And the default setting is already false.

Answer (score 5):

Your server side php has to output something to detect the request is canceled. But as you are likely performing a lengthy sql query, you can't output anything.

But still you can save your connection id into a session, and kill the connection if it's detected:

1. Open session
2. Open sql connection
3. If search_connection_id is set in session, kill the connection
4. Find your connection id, save in session as search_connection_id
5. Close the session - important, else the next request will be blocked in step 1
6. Query database
7. If connection is broken, it's another search killing you in step 3, exit
8. Open session, remove search_connection_id
9. Send response, close sql connection

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers.

I redesigned my search queries like Anigel suggested, with an overwhelming result.

But i think the correct answers to my question are the answers of Marek and Harikrishnan Viswanathar. Both should do what i asked for.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution that I figured out now.

You can set a boolean `isPending` when ajax request is send you can set this value to `true`

After ajax callback is called(success or error) you can set `isPending` to false;

Moreover, you can have a string variable `searchContent` and update this variable when text is changed. So when Ajax Call is not pending and searchContent has content you can send another ajax call.

The best option is to use already written solution for example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ it is very easy and it works very well it has even already built in caching system.

Comment: Well this won't solve my problem because it also sends multiple requests to the server. So it cancels the ajax request, when new data is registered but the server process continues running until the server is configured not to do so.