# Abort previous ajax requests BUT with a delay?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Need to abort all the previous search queries ran by Ajax requests, after the user types/appends next letter in the search box.

I have used the following code to perform the desired results. Declared an object **jqxhr** to abort the ajax requests :

```
var jqxhr = {abort: function () {}}
```

And then on making a call to ajax when user types something new, inititated this object like this :

```
jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ContentAjax.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
   .........OHER CODE HERE.........
```

Now the problem is ajax requests are aborted , if the user types new letter and changing the latest search quesry. But the php is still executing and so is waking up mysql to work for no use, slowing down website badly and I know we can't kill php action with javascript here.

So I tried to delay the ajax request like this :

```
jqxhr = setTimeout(function(){ $.ajax({...code..}) }, 3000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){ jqxhr = $.ajax({...code..}) }, 3000);
```

But none of these worked. It shows an error saying jqxhr.abort() is not defined. or the php action still does not stop.

Please help me in this problem, Thank you.

Comment: `debounce` the keyboard input so that you only initiate a search after a delay to allow multiple keypresses per request rather than after every keypress.

Comment: Anyone? Am just trying to delay the ajax request so in that delay time, I can stop propagation of any needless php/mysql code. This will hugely imporve the searching speed.

Comment: It won't be easy to stop the php/sql parts - more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810339/how-to-cancel-a-php-process-when-ajax-call-is-cancelled

Comment: i think you need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781827/jquery-keypress-event-wait-0-5-seconds-for-another-user-keypress?rq=1

Comment: "I know we can't kill php action with javascript here. " then what are you trying to do with `jqxhr = setTimeout(function(){ $.ajax({...code..}) }, 3000);` ?

Comment: `jqxhr = setTimeout` will set jqxhr to the timeout identifier, not to a jqxhr.

Comment: Viney I was trying to tell, I used that code to delay the ajax and sme time tried to abort the ajax request if it is a previously running ajax request.

Comment: Anyways, Thank you Raymond Nijland, your help has given me something I can definitely use to help myself. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to set an ajax timeout

```
let timeout;

$('#yourId').on('click',function(){
   if(typeof timeout != 'undefined'){ 
       clearTimeout(timeout);
   }
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    //your code here
  },
  200); //milliseconds
});
```